# Access re-execute query when I try to close it

Tags: ms-access

I have worked with different programs such as MySql but for a lesson I have to work on Access and I am not very experienced with it. I have an employee table, and a form to insert tuples, which has an insert button. It does the insertion okay but when I try to close it or change to design view, it tries to re-execute the query and fails because of duplicate values. Anyone familiar with such an error?

Thanks :)

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Yeah, best to show the code that triggers the update

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have created a **bound form**, which inserts its data automatically into the table once the record is saved - this happens on closing or switching to design view (or moving to a different record).

Your Insert button probably inserts the data before the automatic saving, so in result the data is inserted twice.

A bound form is the usual way to insert or edit data in Access, you don't need any code for this.

If you must do it by code, make the form unbound (remove its `.RecordSource`)